# Convergence of gradient descent Monte Carlo Control with function approximation

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning, stochastic-gradient-descent

Can anyone point me in the direction of a formal proof of convergence for a (on/off policy) Monte Carlo control algorithm with (non-)linear function approximation?

- In http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf, Section 11.5, the following is stated, but I have not been able to find any references

  > Among the algorithms investigated so far in this book, only the Monte Carlo methods are true SGD methods. These methods converge robustly under both on-policy and off-policy training as well as for general non-linear (differentiable) function approximators
- On http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/learn-43/lib/photoz/.g/web/glossary/converge.html different results are presented, where I think the MC case counts as 'residual' (thus converging) naturally since the MC target does not depend on the parameters, however also here I do not find references.
- I am a bit confused to find the slide 'Convergence of control algorithms' in http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching_files/FA.pdf, which states MC control does *not* converge for the non-linear case, and only 'chatters around near-optimal values' for the linear case.

Also papers I have been able to find either consider the prediction case or TD-learning. Am I missing something or is it somehow a trivial extension of the prediction case? Are the sources I mentioned contradicting and if so, why?